# Why aren't we Mahmir (stringent) with just Mikvah when ruling leniently on a technicality in Niddah cases?

Tags: minhag, halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, niddah, stringency-chumrah

I know from experience and some introductory study of the laws of Niddah that rabbis typically try to find leniencies wherever possible in issues of family purity. In many instances, a Posek will rely on a technicality to permit a husband and wife to be together even though common sense might dictate that the likelihood is extremely low that a particular stain, or even series of stains, came from any source other than uteran blood.

I appreciate the delicate nature of these questions, as well as the importance of finding ways to be lenient in these matters. I also understand that in many communities, women must trek far distances, even today, to get to a Mikvah, and that even when a Mikvah is easily accessible and clean some women find it difficult to go.

But in instances when the rabbi knows that a woman can easily access a clean, warm, Mikvah with friendly attendants, and the particular woman asking the question enjoys the experience and has no emotional or personal difficulty getting ready or accessing the Mikvah, why isn't she encouraged to be stringent and go "just in case", when the leniency being applied is based on a technicality and the woman wouldn't need to separate from her husband for any extra time (she could go that night)?

I understand that we *don't*. But why not?

Comment: I do not understand your question. When a lady has a question it usually would restart the 7 day counting period. So by the Rabbi being stringent it would be more than that evening. In what case would a women gain by a lenient ruling only that day?

Comment: In a case where something was seen that could potentially put her into a state of Niddah, which hadn't been established yet, and it had already been a few days since the last marital "contact" or "act" because they feared such contact would b4 problematic. This is not unheard of.

Comment: The seven clean days are because, due to Minhag Bnoth Yisrael, we assume all Niddah cases are Zavah cases, which require seven clean days. Niddah itself doesn't require that, but it does require immersion in a Mikvah. That being the case, when ruling leniently, why not still be cautious and go to Mikvah, just in case she is, by the Torah's definition, in a state of Niddah? The technicality is  usually an allowance to assume the blood is either not blood or not from the uterus. If it is, then she should be Niddah.

Comment: @gershon perhaps a post facto mikvah/chatzitza question or maybe an older mareh?

Comment: @Seth niddah still requires 7 days, just not necessarily clean ones.

Comment: @double aa, I'm thinking of an older Mareh. Not sure, but I don't think we're so lenient if the validity of the Tevilah itself is called into question; meanwhile, if I'm not mistaken, most of those questions are not Me'akev to begin with.

Comment: The reason that Rabbis try find all sorts of leniencies is not because the Rabbis feel sorry for the married couple. Halocho does not work like that. 
 - Staining is not bleeding; and only bleeding makes one a Niddah. The staining laws are stringencies that have been universally accepted - but with their own set of rules.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, staining can be a sign of bleeding, though.

Comment: @DannySchoemann like I said, we're being lenient on a technicality (ie., it's a stain, and it's of a certain size or on a certain material that's not Mekabel Tumah, etc.), but common sense would dictate that it's very likely that she's discharging uteran blood.

Comment: @SethJ you can ask the same question when learning Yora Deah. Many questions could probably be answered with "just go kasher the pot" or "better to borrow from neighbors" I think Halacha mandates that we do our best to answer the question at hand and not deflect it otherwise we might end up washing on bread to exempt ourselves from the difficult brachot problem of a Banana Spit with cherries on top :)

Comment: @SethJ for a woman to be a biblical niddah, she needs to to feel the menstruation coming on *from her womb*, like you feel sensations of having to use the bathroom. That "hargasha", feeling, is basically unheard of, and practically speaking a woman is only a biblical niddah if, at the time of seeing blood, she was doing something that could have distracted her from a "hargasha".

Comment: @SethJ Then we say she had one, and just didn't feel it. There are 3 things: 1. She's already bleeding a lot, (ie. pads aren't enough and she's switching to a tampon) 2. she's urinating (and immediately notices blood coming out of her, if a few seconds have elapsed before she looked in the bowl, we assume that the blood came out after and without hargasha.) and 3. She was checking herself with a cloth, inserting it inside her vagina. If those aren't happening, its blood without a hargasha, and is rabbinic, and the general rule is to be lenient when it comes to rabbinic enactments.

Comment: @SethJ my source is I'm taking Chosson classes, first one yesterday!

Comment: @BabySeal, thanks for your insights, and Mazal Tov on being a Chosson!

Comment: @BabySeal Belated mazal tov!  And many acharonim argue on that principle!  (i.e. some acharonim explain that _hargasha_ was part of a ראיה being דרך ראיה and not being abnormal, a la רואה דם בחתיכה.  Today, when lack of _hargasha_ is the norm, its lack does not detract from the normalcy of the ראיה and she is a _niddah de'oraisa_.  Additionally, the Sidrei Tahara based on Rashi understands that the whole point of _hargasha_ is to know that the blood came from her, but if she has tight underwear on and it is surely from her, then lack of hargasha doesn't matter.)

Comment: @yez I was learning a pamphlet from rabbi yosef berger, didn't really have any sources. Are there any who follow those acharonim le maaseh? If so, I think we're approaching a green check mark.

Comment: @BabySeal I also used that pamphlet for my _chosson_ classes. The truth is, implicitly most of us follow these _acharonim_ in some shape or form. By which I mean, if you assume that _Niddah de'oraisa_ only exists with _hargasha_, and most women today do not experience _hargashos_, then we don't really have a _niddah d'oraisa_ today. And yet, open any sefer and you will see the logic of _safek d'oraisa_ and the like thrown around rather freely. The general assumption of modern poskim is, for whatever reason, that when a woman gets her full-blown period, she is a _niddah d'oraisa_.

Comment: @BabySeal The noted exception is the Aruch HaShulchan, who writes that women all really are having _hargashos_, they just don't know what _hargashos_ are and therefore aren't reporting them. But that opens up its own can of worms.

Comment: @BabySeal The 3 things classically are urination, bedika cloths, and sexual intercourse. A full-blown flow is treated the same way re halachos niddah as yEz indicated for whatever reason, but the Gemara's original three examples (cf. Niddah 57b) are as I listed, not as you did.

Comment: @yez that makes sense, I wondered about the regular flow.

Answer (score 3):

*IN GENERAL*

A woman who has been to mikve has a **chazaka** of being "clean" therefore whenever a question comes up (excluding days where she must check herself i.e days 30,31) the Rabbi needs concrete evidence to break that chazaka so any reason to say the stain came from some place else is enough to keep the chazaka in place and it's not considered being lenient. However once a woman sees *nidah blood* then her chazaka is one of a "unclean" woman and in that case you need a strong case to make her "clean" so the same blood she sees during her clean days maybe declared clean while if she saw the same type of blood during a "hefesk tahara" it would be declared unclean.

The concept of Chazaka is one of the main pillers of halacha. However you can look at the following to get an idea how it is used in the laws of Nida

Nida 15a  `כל הנשים בחזקת טהרה לבעליהן`

[Shulchan Aruch Siman 184, Seif 9](http://torahlearning.org/nidah/184-2.htm)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Can you add a source to support it?

Comment: @MonicaCellio  There are good sources for this in Mishneh Torah, Isurai Biyah.  One of the main reasons is that a woman is only tameh from the torah if she has a flow of blood from the main room of the uterus accompanied by a hargasha.  All the laws of stains are D'Rabbinan.   If I have time I'll add them, or you can just read them here:  http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5109n.htm  You can also poke around in the previous chapters for more info.  But since a ketem is rabbinic I would think the principle of a doubt from the torah be stringent, a doubt from rabbinic be lenient applies.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the previous answers, the concept שלא יהא לבו נוקפו may apply here - see Niddah 12a that discourages doing a bedika/examination directly after/before intimate relations - as a matter of course - because it may scare off the husband. If we suggest going to Mikva even when she is 'legally' tahor, they may be uneasy in a similar situation if Mikva is not available.

Answer (score 1):

The Mishnah (Niddah 58b) addresses this question:

מעשה באשה אחת שבאת לפני ר"ע אמרה לו: ראיתי כתם, אמר לה: שמא מכה הייתה ביך? אמרה לו: הן, וחיתה. אמר לה: שמא יכולה להגלע ולהוציא דם? אמרה לו: הן. וטהרה רבי עקיבא. ראה תלמידיו מסתכלין זה בזה, אמר להם: מה הדבר קשה בעיניכם? שלא אמרו חכמים הדבר להחמיר – אלא להקל שנאמר (ויקרא ט"ו) ואשה כי תהיה זבה דם יהיה זובה בבשרה, דם ולא כתם

In other words, a stain does not make a woman a *niddah min ha-torah*, but only *miderabbanan*. The rabbis therefore have the authority to be *meikil* on their rules. See http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%93%D7%94

Comment: The posters here are mistaken. Just because it is uteran blood does not necessarily make her a nidda. Of course if it isnt then she isnt a niddah which this answer says. Even uteran blood the woman has to 'feel' it leaving her body. Exactly what kind of a 'hargasha' feeling is necessary is beyond the scope of this comment. If there is no hargasha feeling she is not a nida min hatora and that is why there are kulos by staining. Not because of the reason this poster mentions.

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about--all I did was quote a mishnah & link to the Wikipedia page on הרגשת נדה.

Comment: Your quote was regarding a 'mako'. A wound and therefore not uteran blood. This is not the issue. Hargosho or lack of it is about uteran blood.

Comment: It is not about דם מכה, but about תלייה בדם מכה--since there is no הרגשה, R. Akiva could be תולה בדם מכה (which works even where the דם is bigger than a כגריס). Look it up.

Comment: Sorry how does hargosho come into dam mako.

Comment: See the last 3 words of my previous comment--the mishnah is not about דם מכה, it is about תלייה. That is why R. Akiva's talmidim were upset, and that is why R. Akiva tells them the דרשה of דם ולא כתם, not דם מן המקור ולא דם מכה. I am done now.

Comment: You may be done. But it is not a simple gemoro. My question still applies if there was no hargosho with this woman why did he have to say it was a dam makko. Even if it was dam nida she would be tohor.

Comment: I notice the chasam sofer chavos daas sidrei tahara discuss it. One simple answer given is that she was already a nidda and counting her seven days. Then even without hargosho it is 'soser' and she has to start again unless it is from a makko.

Comment: @user2800 - the *gemara* at the end of the *sugya* says that we are *toleh* (on a *makko* etc.) by a *kesem* **because** a *kesem* is only *m'dirabanan*. According to many explanations, the underlying reason that a *kesem* is only *m'dirabanan* is because at the biblical level we can **assume** there was no *hargasha*, but *m'derabanan* we worry about an unnoticed *hargasha* like the *gemara* says at the beginning of the *perek* there.

Answer (score 1):

The Chassam Sofer, cited in [Pischei Teshuvos 190:10](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5515), says that the entire concept of *kesamim* (impurity through stains) to which the rules of "technicalities" are applied was really only instituted for the purposes of the laws of ritual purity and impurity, and only for purposes of consistency was it applied to the prohibition of a woman to her husband.  Therefore, nowadays when we do not have practical applications of ritual purity in this regard, the entire concept of *kesamim* is only an artifact, the whole idea only exists in the context in which it was rabbinically instituted, and there is no prohibition to discuss beyond that.

Therefore, in all of these leniencies due to technicalities, it is not being lenient in the face of a prohibition, but rather there is no prohibition of which to speak except for in the context in which the original rabbinic prohibition was created.